# Install mongo php driver centos 6.6

Tags: php, mongodb, centos6

I have a cloud hosted VPS with Centos 6.6 + Direct Admin + PHP 5.6.6 installed by my hosting provider.

I need to have the MongoDB php driver installed to connect to an external mongoDB.

I tried the following installations:

- http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-the-mongodb-php-driver-extension-on-centos-6/
- http://andres.jaimes.net/876/setup-mongo-php-module-centos-6/
- install-mongodb-php-driver-in-centos-6-3 at madcoda com

Also `yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 php-pecl-mongo` does not do the trick

I  have in `/usr/lib64/php/modules/` the following modules:
`bz2.so`,  `calendar.so`,  `ctype.so`,  `curl.so`,  `exif.so`,  `fileinfo.so`,  `ftp.so`,  `gettext.so`,  `iconv.so`,  `json.so`,  **`mongo.so`,**  `phar.so`,  `sockets.so`,  `tokenizer.so`,  `zip.so`

And in `/etx/php.d/` the .ini files that are created for each module.

Installing mongo php driver on an old vps with centos 5.x was not a problem also not on Centos 6.2 with php 5.5.
In these cases the mongo.so was located in the location `/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-xxxxxx/` and had to add it manually to the php.ini

The hosting provider is not supporting any else than the default installation I got.

I really appreciate any help.

Stan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the comment of this answer https://serverfault.com/questions/589877/pecl-command-produces-long-list-of-errors
PEAR had to be reinstalled from the remi-php56 repo because of PHP 5.6 running on the server.
After that I could use `pecl install mongo` and copy the mongo.so to the `/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-xxxxxx/` folder.

`# php -m | grep -i mongo` > `mongo` is running